# What does \u001b[1G\u001b[2K> mean?

Tags: javascript

I'm running through some javascript code and during testing I received this sequence: `\u001b[1G\u001b[2K>` . The entire line was  actual: `tests\\repl\u001b[1G\u001b[2K> tests\\replTest.js`,
 expected: `tests\replTest.js`

What does this mean?

Comment: Those look a lot like [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (in addition to Pointy's comment below, which I took for granted was obvious).

Comment: `\uXXXX` is a hex literal. Look up `001B` in a Unicode chart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are unparsed [ANSI control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences).

- `\u001b[1G` is a "Cursor Horizontal Absolute" code. The 1 means it tries to move the cursor to the first character of the line.
- `\u001b[2K` is a "Erase in Line" code. The 2 makes it mean "Erase the entire line".

It looks like a Unicode escaped dump of the input to a console where someone started typing `tests\repl`, then erased the whole line and instead wrote `> tests\replTest.js`. Could also be the redirect of the console to a file.